# How to correctly display data from two related models in Django ListView

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models as below:

```
class Loo(models.Model):
    loo_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, default="LOO"...)
    loo_from = models.ForeignKey(Harr, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
    loo_fac = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=.....)

class Woo(models.Model):
    woo_item = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, ...)
    woo_loo = models.ForeignKey(Loo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
    woo_dt = models.DateField(null=True, ...)
    woo_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=.....)
```

I am trying to display data from the models using the following listview:

```
class WhoLooView(ListView):
    template_name = "who_loo_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'wholoos'
    model = Loo

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WhoLooView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'woo_item_list': Woo.objects.order_by('-woo_dt'),
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Loo.objects.order_by('loo_from')
```

Note that there can be more than one "**woo_item**" per instance of **Loo** (`id`), so in the listview there will be occasions when for the same **Loo** `id` it will have two instances of **Woo**/s, and thus need to be displayed separately (preferably in two distinct rows).

What I have tried so far creates extra (adjacent) columns for each **Loo** `id` and whichever **Loo**/s have a single instance of **Woo**, are shown in the normal fashion as expected.

How does one take care of such a situation. **Can we have a nested row for cases where there are more than one instance of Woo?**

### Edit

What I have tried (based on your code sample):

```
{% for obj in wholoos %} <!-- wholoos : context object name -->
    {{ obj.loo_type }}
    {% for item in obj.woo_set.all %}
        {{ item.woo_dt }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But now I am not getting anything from the second model **Woo**.

### Edit 2

I am getting the same result as earlier with my original code. Check the image below:

[image]

If you notice (in the image above), **objects # 31 and 34** have one each of child objects (sub-objects). # 32 and 33 have **two each**. I want them to be in **separate rows** and not columns. The reason is, in case there are a number of items for each parent item (which my DB design makes it imperative to be), I would end up with an **enormous number of extra columns for the sub-objects** (and that too **without any column header**).

Answer (score 0):

you can loop the instances of Loo as shown, in your templates, don't have to override the get_context_data.

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
{{ obj.loo_type }}
{% for item in obj.woo_set.all %}
{{ item.woo_dt }}
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have incorporated the code (as suggested by you). But not getting data from **Woo**.

Comment: remove the get_context_data from your views and try

Comment: check my edit. The result is the same as was with my original code.

Comment: Since the **date** field `woo_dt` is designed to have **unique value** for each child object, is there a way to create a `while` loop within the second (**nested**) `for loop`? So that for each **new date** an extra row would be created? Or will it be too much to get the template to handle?

Comment: Is there a way that I may display only the latest (**woo_dt** date-wise)? I tried `Loo.objects.distinct().order_by('id')` but result is the same i.e. I am still getting all values of child objects.